# Not able to Delete a Entries from Database in mvc4

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to delete a record from Database but for a specific row m not able to do it.

This is my Linq Query to delete it

```
 FormSubmit formSubmit = db.FormSubmits.Find(id);
                db.FormSubmits.Remove(formSubmit);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

And i am getting an Error Like this

[image]

I know this is Because of Foreign Key but how to Solve it.In SQL We use NO CHECK but not getting in linq Query.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on this, but [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399369(v=vs.100).aspx) seems the solution in your case:

Specify the `UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never` on your column in your entity. This will disable the update check and will most likely fix your issue.

Another option is to set cascade deletion on the table in the database.

Comment: @Neeraj: was this answer helpful to you?